# Enabling macros in chart data sources in Powerpoint

Tags: excel, charts, embed, powerpoint, vba

I have a Powerpoint file with many charts that I expect many different users to use with their own data.  I'm trying to make this Powerpoint as easy to use as possible by writing VBA into each data source (by data source, I mean the default Excel sheet that is embedded in Powerpoint when you select "Insert" > "Chart").  My goal is to allow them to click the chart, select "Edit data," paste info from a PivotTable into the Excel window that pops up, and let the macro does the rest.  The code I can write myself, but I have a different problem:

I've tried writing macros in these embedded Excel files but they do not save once they are closed (I assume they must be .xls or similar and not .xlsm).  How can I get these macros to save?  I've tried drag and dropping .xlsm files into Powerpoint, but it shows the actual charts on the slide and it's difficult to work with.  I'd like the Excel files to be hidden from Powerpoint view and easily accessed using the "Edit data" option.

I hope this description makes sense, if not I can explain further / answer any questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just provide PowerPoint charts, and have them paste data into each chart's DataSheet in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

Of late, PPT does its best to convert pasted charts into PowerPoint charts (same basic engine as Excel charts but they're not Excel objects).  You can get round this if you copy the chart from XL, switch to PPT and on the Home tab, click the downward pointing arrow below Paste, pick Paste Special and choose to paste as embedded Excel chart object.

You can then doubleclick the pasted object and Excel will launch for in-place editing.

Or you can right-click, choose "Macro enabled worksheet object" or whatever, and then opt to Open or Edit.  Edit gives you in-place editing within the PPT window, Open launches the embedded data in a full copy of Excel.